# How do I get my JupyterLab to show the values of my Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

So my goal is to print the values of my dataframe. Yet that does not seem to be working. I created a dictionary, then used that dictionary to create a dataframe. The console doesn't show anything when i print use print statement. The dictionary isn't even printing. What should I do?

[image: Screenshot of code in JupyterLab.]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"school" : ['amundsen', 'clemente', 'corliss','douglass','eric hs','enger','gage park','harlan','hirsch','hubbard','juarez','kelly'],
        "DO2019" : [6,0.9,2.3,0.6,3,16.5,10.6,10.3,11.2,7.4,5.5,5.5],
        "median_income" : [50065, 58987, 40394,28059,42809,40394,37367,40394,40176,37367,42575,42809] 
       }
print(data)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
print(df)
```

Comment: Please do not take offence but have you used JupyterLab for other purposes? Ie can you print simple values etc? because your code is fine and should work ok

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Did you run the cell? shift-return?

Comment: also>>>. df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Comment: @piterbarg I have to use for the assignment.

Comment: @SxolarBit Python 3.

Comment: @Merlin I tried shift-return also i tried df = pd.DataFrame(data), the console goes from Busy->Restarting->Idle.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to display the data frame of your sample code in Jupyter notebook, can you open any new Python notebook and see if you can display the sample output, if not then onew way is to stop the notebook and restart again, sometimes this has happened to me and restarting helped me.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to run `jupyter notebook` command and it will open a tree of your files in your browser. Then you can create a new notebook and copy this code in a cell and run it using the play button at the top or pressing `shift+endter`.

you dont need print(df) only place df in the cell and run it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df
```

it will show your df and if you want you can only show head or tail of the df:

```
df.head(5)

df.tail(5)
```

Comment: _you dont need print(df) only place df in the cell and run it_ Yes, but `print()` should still work, right? _it will show your df and if you want you can only show head or tail of the df_ I don't think that's particularly relevant.